# Problem in understanding that why this works as a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below, I have used **total** as a variable to hold the value of the function **sum**. Since the **total** is not defined as function so why does this work when in the last line of code it says **print(total(10,20))**. Why it took the arguments using the **total** instead of using the arguments which I gave to **sum**, Since **total** is not a function so it shouldn't be able to take arguments.
I am new to python and just started to learn about functions in python, this code was used in the tutorial that I am learning from, he was teaching about function nesting.

```
def sum(num1, num2):
    def new(num1, num2):
        return num1 + num2
    return new

total = sum(3,4)
print(total(10, 20))
```

Comment: `sum` returns the function, not the function result. What output did you expect to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since total is not a function so it shouldn't be able to take arguments.*

It is function. Python has built-in module [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) which is handy in such situations, for example if you want to check if something is function:

```
import inspect
def sum(num1, num2):
    def new(num1, num2):
        return num1 + num2
    return new

total = sum(3,4)
print(inspect.isfunction(total))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Ability to return function is one of signs that functions in python are [first class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it now. Just one more thing, total became a function without even defining it like I did with the other functions of sum and new, right?

Comment: You did called `sum` function which returned function (defined as `new` inside it) which was placed under `total`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment by @Sayse sum returns a function which you can see if you look at the type of total. By modifying the parameters of new you will get a different result:

```py
def sum(num1, num2):
    def new(x, y):
        return num1 + num2
    return new

total = sum(3,4)
print(type(total))
print(total(10, 20))#prints 7
```